# A Question Regarding an Often Used Statement made in a Theorem about convergence of a Series.

Tags: sequences-and-series, definition

My version of definition of series is :

If $X=(x_n)$ is a sequence in $\Bbb R$ then the series generated by $X$ is the sequence $S=(s_n)$ defined as

$$s_1=x_1,$$
$$s_2=s_1+x_2,$$
$$s_3=s_2+x_3,$$
$$...$$
$$s_k=s_{k-1}+x_k,$$

and so on. The numbers $x_n$ are called the $n-th$ term of the series and the numbers $s_n$ are called the partial sums of the series. If the sequence $S$ converges at a point (in
$\Bbb R$) then, we say, this seies is convergent, and call this limit the sum of the series. If this limit does not exist, we call the series to be diverging.

It is convenient to use the symbol such as $$\sum x_n\tag 1$$ to denote the infinite series $S,$ generated by the sequence $X=(x_n)$ and also denote the value, $\lim S$ in case the limit exists. Thus, the symbol $(1)$ above, is merely "a way of exhibiting" an infinite series whose convergence or divergence is to be tested.

---

(This definition is rather a popular one.)

In short, I regard,

> "*A series is a special type of sequence generated by a sequence.*"

The problem arised, when I was going through some tests related to convergence of a series, for example: Comparison Test of First Kind, Limit Test, D'Alambert's ratio Test, etc. Say for example, in the Comparison Test was given as:

> **Let $ \sum u_n$ and $\sum v_n$ be two series of positive real numbers** and there is a natural number $m$ such that $u_n\leq kv_n,\forall n\geq m,$ $k$ being a fixed positive number. Then, $\sum u_n$ is convergent if $\sum v_n$ is divergent.

But the part of the statement, where it said,  "**Let $ \sum u_n$ and $\sum v_n$ be two series of positive real numbers**" (at the beginning) seems ambiguous to me. This is because, I really don't know what is meant by the phrase "*series of positive real numbers*". Does the phrase, "*series of positive real numbers*" means that the series $\sum u_n$ and $\sum v_n$ that are generated by the respective sequences $(u_n)$ and $(v_n)$ has all terms in the sequence,i.e  $(u_n)$ or $(v_n)$ positive ? (In other words, does the phrase implies $u_n,v_n\gt 0,\forall n\in\Bbb N$ ?) Or is it just they mean that the each of the terms in the sequence of partial sums of *each (given) series* are positive ?

Comment: A series of positive reals means that each summand is positive.  Thus, if our series is $\sum a_n$, the assumption would be that each $a_n$ is real and $>0$,  not $≥0$ as you suggest.

Comment: @lulu I fixed it in OP. So, this means that  if the series is $\sum u_n$, then the the phrase(say), "Let $\sum u_n$ be a series of positive real numbers" means, that *all the **terms of sequences** generating the series, i.e $(u_n)$ has all it's terms positive or better put, as $u_k\gt 0, \forall k\in\Bbb N$*, right ?

Comment: well, that's an unusual phrasing.  I don't know what "sequences generating the series" means unless you literally just mean the sequence $\{u_n\}$, in which case, yes.  All it means is that the $u_n$ are real and positive.

Comment: @lulu By the phrase , "sequence generating the series $\sum u_n$" , i.e mean the sequence $u_n$. Are you bothered because I **mistakenly** wrote an extra $s$ i.e "sequence**s** generating the series" instead of "sequence generating the series" ?

Comment: There is no notion of a sequence "generating a series".  Why introduce that concept?  It seems confusing.

Comment: @lulu See the definition, I wrote in the beginning. It's given in a book called "Real Analysis" called Bartle Sherbert.

Comment: Well, personally, I wouldn't use that language.  We already have a notation for the $\{u_n\}$, I don't see any advantage in elaborating on that.  But, yes.  I agree that with this application of that definition.

Comment: @lulu Again a boring confirmation (but seems necessary to me, at this point): So, this means that  if the series is $\sum u_n$, then the the phrase(say), "Let $\sum u_n$ be a series of positive real numbers" means, that *all the **terms of sequence** generating the series, i.e $(u_n)$ has all it's terms positive or better put, as $u_k\gt 0, \forall k\in\Bbb N$*, right ?

Comment: Positive *and real*.  But, yes.

Comment: @lulu You mean in the last part, where I wrote, *has all it's terms positive* should be changed to *has all it's terms  positive and real* ?

Comment: Yes.  Perhaps that's just a technical note, if you feel that saying $a>0$ already implies that $a$ is a real number (I would disagree, but most of the time, that would probably be a fair assumption).  But suppose we said that the series $\sum a_n$ had positive, rational, terms.  That would mean that, for each $n$, $a_n>0$ and $a_n\in \mathbb Q$.  There the distinction would clearly not be technical.

Comment: @lulu So, the final conclusion is:  If there is a  series (suppose), $\sum u_n$, then the the phrase(say), "Let $\sum u_n$ be a series of positive real numbers" means, that *all the **terms of sequence** generating the series, i.e $(u_n)$ has all it's terms positive and real or better put, as $u_k\gt 0, \forall k\in\Bbb N$*.  This is it , correct? (Now, this get's tiring, but I dont have any option either!)

Comment: You keep asking the same question, and I keep repeating the same answer.  Again:  I don't feel that writing $u_k>0$ automatically implies that $u_k\in \mathbb R$, so I think that needs to be added. Thus I would modify your sentence by saying "or better put, as $u_k>0$ and $u_k\in \mathbb R$ $\forall k\in \mathbb N$"

Comment: @lulu This is perfect. Thanks, for your co-operation. Clarifications, can get painful at times truly in an online networking media. My issue is resolved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A “series of blah numbers” means a series where each of its terms has property blah. It need not be true that the partial sums have property blah too.

I think titling your post “A dilemma” is a bit strong. Just “A question regarding$\ldots$” would be fine.